# Why we write Employee emp = new Employee()

Tags: c#, dart

Just an academic question, why many programming languages have following like syntax for instantiation :

```
Employee emp = new Employee()
```

I mean, we don't use something like `Employee emp = new Vehicle()`. So, why not just say `Employee emp` or `new Employee emp` too instantiate.

Am I missing something too fundamental ?

Comment: Before = you make a variable declaration so that this variable exists. After = you write what you want to assign to that variable, so you make a new Employee instance.

Comment: Totally agree. However, it could have been achieved by just saying `emp = new Employee()`. This will take care of both - declaration and instantiation, isn't it ?

Comment: No, because this variable is not declared. I guess this was made to prevent mistyping a variable and declaring a new one tho, and we can do `var emp = new Employee()`

Comment: I can't tell if this is really an academic question or if you're trying to start an argument.

Comment: Apologies ! I didn't mean to start an argument. It's genuine question I've since many years.

Comment: There's significant discussion on this topic available and it obviates this question entirely.

Comment: If you really want to know why a language is designed a certain way, read *everything ever written* by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Your simple code statement does **two things** as the first comment indicates.  1) `Employee emp` declares a variable and the type.  The compiler has to know the type or how it can be determined.  2) `... = new Employee()` actually creates the instance.  This part need not accompany the first.  It could be hundreds of lines of code away, or even in another file or class.  They only look a little redundant when next to each other in the same line which happens much less in real world apps.

Comment: @madreflection, will do. I was looking for something which Cider answered. "when handling inherited object, it is very common that the reference type and the instance type are not the same." I never meant to argue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can use `var` in order to let the compiler decide the data type of the variable.
For example:

```
var i = 5;
```

In addition, when handling inherited object, it is very common that the reference type and the instance type are not the same.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes, I know 'var'. However, my question is very specific and is about the syntax C c = new C()

Comment: Does the last sentence of my answer answers your question?

Comment: I guess. Do you mean, Car c = new Vehicle() is a valid statement ?

Comment: It is not, but the other way around is valid:
Vehicle v = new Car()

Comment: Thanks ! That answers my question.

Comment: You probably did not ask, but the 'new' has also a meaning. In C++ you can allocate elements either statically or dynamically. When you use the 'new' keyword, it means you use dynamic allocation. C# **inherited** the syntax from C++.

Answer (score 2):

Well, every class in C# used by reference. Writing `Employee emp = new Employee()` assigns to value `emp` reference to object of the class `Employee` (pointer to somewhere in the sea of objects), and you can't use class by value, because of garbage collector and possible reallocation. Class objects are stored in the heap.

If you programmed in C++ (I believe you did), you know, that analogous code will
return *pointer* to object in the heap, not the object itself.

But C# have one custom type which can be passed by value, not by reference:
`struct`. And writing code

```
struct Employee{
...
}

...

Employee emp;
emp.cnt = 5
```

is perfectly valid, because struct initialized automatically, as do other value-types in C#.

It is just language design, nothing more.

Also CLR makes sure, that no object can be casted to type that is not defined in `implicit/explicit` cast constructions. That is what makes regular C# safe. But that may not be true in `unsafe` blocks. I used them only once and don't know much about them. Only that some operations that are not possible in `safe` blocks possible here.

Comment: In C++, `struct` and `class` are exactly the same thing and have identical semantics. The only difference between them is whether the default visibility of members is `public` or `private`. I realize you're talking about C#, not C++, just wanted to avoid possible confusion over the C++ analogy.

Comment: @MichaelGeary i will edit my post, because i meant to say about C#'s `struct`

Answer (score 1):

### First, it's not recommended

While this question might fall into "primarily opinion based" there *is* a best practice to use implicit typing along with the `new` keyword because the type is very obvious thanks to the type's constructor.

Use of `var` is known as *implicit typing* and it means you won't have to modify your code when, for example, a database provider must change.

### Second, there's at least one time explicit typing makes sense

Numbers.  Specifically `decimal` and the variety of integer sizes.  Consider the following:

```
var num = 0;
```

With no other hinting, I'm allowing the compiler to decide the size, in memory, of that variable.  Right now, that's `Int32` and that's fine ... but what if that number has to go somewhere else?  What if I'm writing that to a TCP socket and the client on the other end is expecting the serialized bytes of a `ULong` or `UInt16`

When working with numbers, and even more critically with *money*, explicit typing should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to declare variable for storing information about the class(i.e. instance of that class)

To answer your question, we cannot use object/variable without declaring it, it is necessary to store your class instance in object/variable for maintaining information and using it further.

You can use scala where you can declare variable using **val** or **var**,

**val** is used when variable is used as constant ie. it won't change in future, otherwise use **var**

Answer (score 0):

Intersting question 
First of all it depends on the programmimg language and where you want to declare the variable. If the variable is a member of your class then you have to declare a specific type. That is because, for some languages like C#, the compiler is creating a dll which has all the information about your class including class members. For that it need to be specific type.

We can concider C# as a safe programming language because it doesn't allow changing the type of a variable when first it is declared and assigned. However for some years ago C# inroduced the dynamic type and distroyed all that concepts